# Point to Point environment ->Restful

Tags: rest

After I read that sentence:

> SOAP was designed for a distributed computing environment whereas
>   REST was designed for a point to point environment.

I searched about DCE and point to point environment. I learned about DCE but I found nothing about point to point environment. So what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe "SOAP was designed for a distributed computing environment" boils down to meaning SOAP is an RPC mechanism. From what I understand, "point to point environment" is really just another way of saying that the protocol implementing the style is client/server and only supports unicast addressing.

It's a meaningless contrast, really. And, if my understanding is correct, the "point to point environment" bit is rubbish - HTTP might not support anything other than unicast addressing of resources, but that doesn't mean that any other protocol supporting the RESTful style, hypothetical or otherwise, couldn't have an addressing mechanism for resources that mapped onto potentially multiple resources.

Of course, I'm only making an educated guess.

Comment: IMO, SOAP contains the schema details of the message type and other interface details , so it can be forwarded by some middle ware or some other server , to any other server depending upon that information, but REST is meant to work with two end points which are closely coupled.

Answer (score -1):

**REST** - Used on the web for a larger scale internet applications and websites(twitter.com) Point To Point = internet.

**SOAP** - Used in Busienss Systems, Commonly Used With Existing XML Schema from third parties.

Comment: Business systems can use REST just fine. REST can use XML. REST does scale much better than SOAP though, yes.

Comment: Its Typical Usage Scenarios, Its Not Always Going To Be Your Preference